# Python 3.5 requests for clawing

Tags: python-requests, python-3.5

I have a coding problem regarding Python 3.5 web clawing.

I try to use 'requests.get' to extract the real link from 'http://www.baidu.com/link?url=ePp1pCIHlDpkuhgOrvIrT3XeWQ5IRp3k0P8knV3tH0QNyeA042ZtaW6DHomhrl_aUXOaQvMBu8UmDjySGFD2qCsHHtf1pBbAq-e2jpWuUd3'.  An example of the code is like below:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://www.baidu.com/link?url=ePp1pCIHlDpkuhgOrvIrT3XeWQ5IRp3k0P8knV3tH0QNyeA042ZtaW6DHomhrl_aUXOaQvMBu8UmDjySGFD2qCsHHtf1pBbAq-e2jpWuUd3')

c = response.url
```

I expected that 'c' should be 'caifu.cnstock.com/fortune/sft_jj/tjj_yndt/201605/3787477.htm'. (I remove http:// from the link as I can't post two links in one question.)
However, it doesn't work, and keeps return me the same link as I putted in.
Can anyone help on this. Many thanks in advance.

#

Thanks a lot to Charlie. 
I have found out the solution. I first use .content.decode to read the response history, but that will be mixed up with many irrelevant info. I then use .findall to extract the redirect url from the history, which should be the first url displayed in the response history. Then, I use requests.get to retrieve the info. Below is the code:

```
rep1 = requests.get(url)
cont = rep1.content.decode('utf-8')
extract_cont = re.findall('"([^"]*)"', cont)
redir_url = extract_cont[0]
rep = requests.get(redir_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider looking into the response headers for a 'location' header.

```
response.headers['location']
```

You may also consider looking at the response history, which contains a response for each response instance in a chain of redirects

```
response.history
```

Comment: I tried to look at .histroy. It returned with []. I also tried print(.headers), which returned me :

Comment: {'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, must-revalidate', 'Date': 'Tue, 18 Oct 2016 02:49:53 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html, text/html;charset=utf8', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Expires': 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1;mode=block', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'BWS/1.1'}....I am Python learner...please advise.

Comment: Also, the tricky thing in here is that the same code works fine with my friend's computer in China, while for me in Australia it doesn't work.......

Comment: Is everything up to date? The docs say response.url should return the final redirect's URL

Answer (score 0):

Your sample URL doesn't redirect; The response is a 200 and then it uses a JavaScript window.location change. The requests library won't support this type of redirect.

```
<script>window.location.replace("http://caifu.cnstock.com/fortune/sft_jj/tjj_yndt/201605/3787477.htm")</script>
<noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://caifu.cnstock.com/fortune/sft_jj/tjj_yndt/201605/3787477.htm'"></noscript>
```

If you know you will always be using this one service, you could parse the response, maybe using regex.

If you don't know what service will always be used and also want to handle every possible situation, you might need to instantiate a WebKit instance or something and somehow try to determine when it finally finishes. I'm sure there's a page load complete event which you could use, but you still might have pages that do a window.location change after the page is loaded using a timer. This will be very heavyweight and still not cover every conceivable type of redirect.

I recommend starting with writing a special handler for each type of edge case and fallback on a default handler that just looks at the response.url. As new edge cases come up, write new handlers. It's kind of the 'trial and error' approach.

Comment: thanks a lot Charlie. I just found out this problem as well. Could you mind to suggest some possible solution for this?

Comment: Okay, I added some other ideas.

Comment: rep1 = requests.get(url)
            cont = rep1.content.decode('utf-8')
            extract_cont = re.findall('"([^"]*)"', cont)
            redir_url = extract_cont[0]
            rep = requests.get(redir_url)

Comment: I spent a few days on this problem. Above is my solution, which might be helpful who may have the same problem as I did.             rep1 = requests.get(url)
            cont = rep1.content.decode('utf-8')
            extract_cont = re.findall('"([^"]*)"', cont)
            redir_url = extract_cont[0]
            rep = requests.get(redir_url)